# How to fix Entity Framework partial class method call?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm using partial class in Entity Framework to calculate age of a person from a view called vPerson.

```
private string _age;
public string Age
{
    get{return CalculateAge();}
}

private string CalculateAge()
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(System.DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Year - _dob.Value.Year); 
}
```

However, when I use Age in the EF select, it doesn't process the query. Here is the code:

```
public IQueryable getData()
{
         var res = from p in _context.vPerson.Select
         (
             p=>new PersonDetail
             {
                name = p.name,
                dob = p.dob,
                age = p.Age
             }
         );
         return res;
 }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is that EF cannot translate your calculation to an SQL query. There are two options to go around this:

1. Materialize the result set using a .toList() after vPerson and then append an .AsQueryable() to the end. Note that this way you are losing deferred execution of the query.
2. Try rewriting this operation using Entity Functions, which EF can translate to SQL. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much Dimitris, the first option worked like a charm =)

Answer (score 0):

EF queries are translated into an SQL query. A custom property does not exist as a column in the table, so it cannot be translated into a query. For the same reason you cannot have methods in an EF query (except for specific DB methods such as [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) - they cannot be translated into an SQL query. So you really have two problems: a custom property and a method call. Your only option is to make the calculation directly in the query.